# Openoffice-calc can't change the date format of a column

Tags: mysql, format, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

In openoffice calc I open a csv file downloaded from the internet.

One of the columns is for date. The date is in format dd/mm/yy. It is also aligned left (which I think it is saved as text).

I want to modify the date format to yyyy-mm-dd so i can fit it in a mysql table that i have created and in which i hava a column with data type date (so it requires the format i mentioned before).

So I select the column 'Date' in openoffice calc and try to change the format from what it is to the one i want. Nothing is happening. No changes at all.

Any suggestion? Has anything to do with character set or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.csv'
  INTO TABLE my_table
  CHARACTER SET utf8
  FIELDS
    TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES
    TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES
  (@date, col_a, col_b, etc)
SET
  date_col = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%d/%m/%Y')
;
```

Comment: you certainly set me on the right track. but still have problems. my csv file has about 2000 rows. it only process the first row and these are the errors i get :`Warning (Code 1265): Data truncated for column 'amount_to_vat' at row 1
Error (Code 1411): Incorrect datetime value: '19/12/2011' for function str_to_date
Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'rid' at row 1`. also what is the @date? also the rid column is auto-increment and on the csv there is no such column. is that a problem?

Comment: Chances are that your line termination is something other than `'\r\n'`?  Maybe just `'\n'`?  No problem with `rid` being absent from CSV (just omit it from the column list in the `LOAD DATA` command.  `@date` is just a user variable into which the first column from the CSV in the example above is assigned, so that it can then be passed to `STR_TO_DATE()` and finally used to set the column `date_col`.

Comment: you were right for the line terminator. Also the str_to_date solved the problem. The only warning that remains is this:`Warning (Code 1264): Out of range value for column 'rid' at row 1`. Now it processes all the rows but it can't do the auto increment correct. At the first row it puts the highest number it can get as int and then it skips all the next rows.

Comment: finally the problem with code 1264 warning was that i had declared the rid as int(11) data type. but the int data type (signed) has 10 digits. so i set it as int without declaring the number of the digits and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

If you select one cell and look at the cell contents in the top 'formula' box - does it start with a single quote ? That means, it is imported as text. Try remove the quote, and the date suddenly behaves as a date (and uses your display preferences for that cell).

There is a funny hack to remove these leading quotes using search and replace. Select your column, do a search and replace, click more options, current selection only, use regular expressions :

```
search ^(.*)$
replace &
```

in regexp speak, this means `search anything and replace it by itself`. in OO, this removes the leading quote.

Answer (score 0):

it's in the import/open dialog, you have to tell it that the columns is a date, then it all works.